# Type safety with name and register, using custom input component with react hook form

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I'm not a typescript guru and could use some help here.

I'm using a custom input component for the purposes of ensuring consistent error handling/accessibility and presentation and it "works", but I've lost some type checking along the way.

I'm currently using FormProvider and useFormContext to more easily access what I need directly within the InputComponent without needing to pass props through multiple levels.

When trying to register the "otherfield" input for isntance, I receive the following error, as I'd expect

`Argument of type '"otherfield"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"email" | "password" | "firstName"'`

But when using the InputComponent, I'll receive no type errors when trying to pass a "name" not matching my type(inferred from my schema) — which is used within the register().

I'm just looking for a little guidance on how to improve this to ensure there is type checking on the "name" property to match the available options.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import RHFSubPerson from "./components/RHFSubPerson";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import InputComponentRHF from "./components/InputComponentRHF";

type ISampleRHFFormComplex = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstName: string;
};

const sampleRHFFormComplexSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().required(),
  password: yup.string().required(),
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
});

const formSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<ISampleRHFFormComplex> = (
  data: ISampleRHFFormComplex
) => {
  console.log("Form data is ", data);
};

const SampleRHFFormComplex = () => {
  const methods = useForm<ISampleRHFFormComplex>({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      firstName: "",
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(sampleRHFFormComplexSchema),
    mode: "all",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(methods.formState.errors);
  }, [methods.formState.errors]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>SampleRHFFormComplex</h1>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <input {...methods.register("otherfield")} />
        <InputComponentRHF
          name="otherfield" // Where I'd also expect to see a warning
          label="First Name"
          type="text"
          columns="6"
        />
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(formSubmitHandler)}>
          <RHFSubPerson />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit me" />
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default SampleRHFFormComplex;
```

```
import React from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import { FormGroup, Label } from "reactstrap";
import { IInputOption } from "../util/types";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

interface IInputComponentRHFProps {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  id?: string;
  label: string;
  columns?: string;
  options?: IInputOption[] | null;
}

export const InputComponentRHF = (props: IInputComponentRHFProps) => {
  const { name, label, type, columns = "12" } = props;

  const {
    control,
    register,
    formState,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useFormContext();

  const validClass = Boolean(
    _.get(formState.dirtyFields, name) &&
      !_.get(formState.errors, `${name}.message`)
  )
    ? "is-valid"
    : "";

  const error = _.get(formState.errors, `${name}.message`);

  return (
    <FormGroup className={`col-${columns}`} id={`${name}-group`}>
      {(() => {
        switch (type) {
          default:
            return (
              <>
                <Label for={name}>{label}</Label>
                <input
                  {...register(name)}
                  className={`form-control ${validClass}`}
                />
              </>
            );
        }
      })()}
      {error ? <p className="text-danger py-2">{error?.toString()}</p> : null}
    </FormGroup>
  );
};

export default InputComponentRHF;
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rhf-with-yup-resolver-73pq7l?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900063b6fg2rxc1gc%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900023b6fdk47hgva%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900033b6f81mtjemw%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900053b6f5ymn8crf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrutcap900023b6fdk47hgva%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900023b6fdk47hgva%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap800013b6f9jen8bjh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clruyepdt00ff3b6fat2rutt4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A48%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A29%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A48%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A29%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clruyepdt00ff3b6fat2rutt4%2522%257D%252C%2522clrutcap900053b6f5ymn8crf%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900053b6f5ymn8crf%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900043b6fg0sh7ojq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900043b6fg0sh7ojq%2522%257D%252C%2522clrutcap900033b6f81mtjemw%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrutcap900033b6f81mtjemw%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)